# How to get deeply nested JSON object in Java

Tags: java, json

I have a JSON string where i want to get the value of one field which is nested in multiple objects. How can I get that field in a nice and performant way? Here's the code I tried so far. It's working, but it's quite lengthy code. I'm looking for a better solution.

**Json Response**

```
{  
   "status":"success",
   "response":{  
      "setId":1,
      "response":{  
         "match":{  
            "matches":{  
               "matchesSchema":{  
                  "rules":[  
                     {  
                        "ruleId":"Abs"
                     }
                  ]
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
```

**lengthy code**:

```
JsonParser jp=new JsonParser();
Object obj = jp.parse(JSONString); 
JSONObject jsonObject =(JSONObject) (obj);
JSONObject get1 = jsonObject.getJSONObject("response");
JSONObject get2 = get1 .getJSONObject("response");
JSONObject get3 = get2 .getJSONObject("match");
JSONObject get4 = get3 .getJSONObject("matches");
JSONObject get5 = get4 .getJSONObject("matchesSchema");
JSONObject get6 = get5 .getJSONObject("rules");
JSONArray result = get6 .getJSONArray("rules");
JSONObject result1 = result.getJSONObject(0);
String lat = result1 .getString("rule");
```

The result is
`ruleId = Abs`

is there a good alternative for fetching the `ruleId` from the nested json object (something like `response.response.match.matches.matchesSchema.rules.ruleId`)

Comment: Improve grammar and question

Answer (score 1):

You can use Jackson's `JsonNode` with JsonPath to get `ruleId` as follows:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
JsonNode jsonObj = mapper.readTree(JSONString);
String lat = jsonObj.at("/response/response/match/matches/matchesSchema/rules/0/ruleId").asText()
```

It's also `null`-safe and returns a `MissingNode` object on a null node that returns an empty string when you do a `.asText()`

Comment: Thanks you  But i thinking to write code like first search rules is present or not if present fetch rules.  /response/response/match/matches/matchesSchema/rules/0/ruleId i dont want to use  all the object name . i want to write like if rules object available then it will fetch value

Comment: I'm sorry, it wasn't clear from your question that you wanted such logic. It really is a small change to the above code. Do a `jsonObj.at("<path_until_possible_null>");` assigning the result to a `var`, do a null-check and extract as listed

Answer (score 1):

It's super easy with [JsonPath](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath).

```
String ruleId = JsonPath.read(jsonString, "$.response.response.match.matches.matchesSchema.rules[0].ruleId");
```

Or if you read the path multiple times, it's better to pre-compile JsonPath expression

```
JsonPath ruleIdPath = JsonPath.compile("$.response.response.match.matches.matchesSchema.rules[0].ruleId");
String ruleId = ruleIdPath.read(json);
```